# Batching multiple AJAX requests into one request

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, monitoring

We are monitoring user actions on the website. We capture the events and send list of events to our server. So we want to batch certain number of events(requests) and send as one request to our server. It help us to reduce the number of connections(hit) to our server.

How do i acheive it in JavaScript?

Comment: Well, just like you described it. Have the JavaScript store the requests locally, and send a batch of them to the server whenever you consider the volume is enough. Or is that a trick question?

Comment: I thought of pusing into queue(array), and send it to server when queue size reached certain limit. But it missed out requests when size is not reached the limit and page is refreshed or navigated.

Comment: add a timeout to flush the queue periodically. If the user loads another page, you will probably want to cancel the requests altogether. If not, you can catch the onunload event and flush the requests from there too.

Comment: Great. 'beforeunload' will help me.